# $("body").delegate em plain javascript

Tags: javascript

Estou implementando uma `class` de calendário, porém quando eu clico no botão pra ir para o próximo mês ou anterior, os eventos das div's do dia selecionado do evento click não funcionam mais. Se eu utilizar o `$("body").delegate` do jQuery isso não seria problema, mas agora sem jQuery está me dando um certo trabalho.

Obs.: O calendário é recriado.

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".in-range");
elements.forEach(element => {
    var classList = element.classList;
    element.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
        executaData( element.getAttribute('date-value') );
        } else alert('Weekend\'s days not available');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

O problema foi resolvido, a implementação ficou desta maneira:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
if (event.target.matches('.in-range'))
    console.log(event.target.getAttribute('date-value'));
}, false);
```